# Deploying node.js web server with file uploads not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am currently working on a web application for myself where I can upload mathematical related notes. The files are stored and pulled from the server using fs filesystem. The files are stored only in json files. If I run my application/server under localhost:3000 it works seamlessly and the files are uploaded, stored and pulled correctly. But as I deployed my server on Cyclic the functionality of storing and saving files was gone and I do not know why and I do not know how to fix this issue. The code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/FynnZentner/WebTeX.git) and the deployed site can be visited under https://glorious-cyan-tweed-jacket.cyclic.app (password: Password, user: User). E.g. if I create a folder and then click on it, I get `Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...files.forEach...')`. Can anyone please help me with this issue because this is my first project and I put a lot of work in it. Thanks in advance!

I already tried to upload my project to other services but the issue is still there. Furthermore, I read a few articles but none of them really helped me.